# Set a Managed Metadata Column Default Value in SharePoint with REST

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

Has anyone ever successfully set the default value of a managed metadata (single select) column in a SharePoint library/list via Power Automate/REST API?

I tried the following in Power Automate:

_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Test_ContentTypeAutomation')/fields/getbytitle('Department-name')

body: { '__metadata': { 'type':'SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField' }, 'DefaultValue': 'HR|d106fc07-5f11-43ca-995f-6aae1ea' }

But I got a "parameter __metadata does not exist in method GetByTitle"

Thanks,
Sylvie

Answer (score 0):

try this instead: "type": "Collection(SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue)"

But I am not sure if it will work, working with Taxonomy is quite tricky with the REST v1 API. If it doesn't work try to take a look at the TaxonomyHiddenList

_api/Web/lists/getByTitle('TaxonomyHiddenList')/items(7)

I've modified some values doing this on the body

```
{
    "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.Data.TaxonomyHiddenListListItem"
    },
    "Title": "Title2"
}
```

Hope It helps

Marti,